# How to do Tabs using jquery-ui, haml & sinatra?

Tags: jquery-ui, sinatra, haml

I have sinatra, jquery-ui and haml. I want to replicate http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default in haml.

this is may Sinatra rb file

```
require 'sinatra' 
get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

I downloaded jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom.zip and unzipped it into `public` directory

then I created index.haml file that sits in `views` directory

```
%html
    %head
        %title simple tab page
        %script{:type => "text/javascript", :src  => "external/jquery/jquery.js"}
        %script{:type => "text/javascript", :src  => "jquery-ui.min.js"}
        %link{:rel => :stylesheet, :type => :"text/css", :href => "jquery-ui.min.css"}
        %link{:rel => :stylesheet, :type => :"text/css", :href => "jquery-ui.structure.min.css"}
        %link{:rel => :stylesheet, :type => :"text/css", :href => "jquery-ui.theme.min.css"}
        :javascript
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
            });
    %body
        %div#tabs
            %ul
                %li
                    %a{:href => "#devices-tab"}Devices
                %li
                    %a{:href => "#options-tab"}System Options
                %li
                    %a{:href => "#reports-tab"}Reports
                %li
                    %a{:href => "#notes-tab"}Notes
            #devices-tab
                Devices Page

            #options-tab
                Options Page

            #reports-tab
                Reports Page

            #notes-tab
                Notes Page
```

but what I get does not look like UI-lightness theme

[image]

Tested with ff & chrome. Both have not error showing on console. All resources (.js and .css) were loaded.

Clicking the text (Notes, Reports ..) would update the text 'below tabs'.

using

- haml (4.0.7)
- sinatra (1.4.6)
- on ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x64-mingw32]

Could someone tell me how I can make tabs work?

**update**

Thanks to @Siguza I tried to use https://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.11.4.zip and it worked!

Then I downloaded custom build from http://jqueryui.com/download/ where I just simply clicked 'download' button. I did not select nor unchecked anything. The result is like that

[image]

Comment: Can you open this page in your webbrowser and check the error console (either Firefox or Chrome?).

Comment: @evotopid: updated my question: added versions of gems and that there is no error in console. Which I checked before posting my question but did not mention...

Comment: When building your custom zip, which features did you uncheck?

Comment: I tried this but it worked for me. I was, however, using slightly older versions of the jQuery libs because I used Rack-JQuery etc to load them in and I'm using Ruby v2.2.2. I've [put my repo on Github](https://github.com/yb66/SO-question-32035006), so see if it works for you and the slight differences may shed some light.

Comment: @Siguza: I think I did not uncheck anything :-)

Comment: @iain: `'bundle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` could do it using Sinatra only? I do not use RoR.

Comment: Bundler is just a sensible way to manage gem dependencies, it's not Rails specific. `gem install bundler` and the code will be runnable, or you can install the gems in Gemfile by hand if it really floats your boat.

Comment: @iain:hm your code does exactly what I want. Any suggestions how to fix mine? Yours it too advanced for me.

Comment: I've taken pity on you and pushed a version to the [`without-rack-jq` branch](https://github.com/yb66/SO-question-32035006/tree/without-rack-jq) :) The only significant differences I can see between yours and mine are 1) the gems are sandboxed by the bundler command I gave you (always a good thing to do, btw) and 2) I'm using 2 spaces instead of 4 in the haml, which with significant whitespace could have an effect 3) I split up the index into a layout and an index. Change each one at a time in your project till it works and you'll have the answer.

Comment: sorry but I don't know how to make it work. This solution doesn't contain any .js files. What should I do?

Comment: @Radek So your zip should be equal to the [1.11.4 stable](https://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.11.4.zip)? Mind giving that one a try then?

Comment: @Siguza: of course I don't mind. Actually it works with above zip. Just by comparing file sizes of new files and the old one I can say that all .css files are different. I do not think I inlcuded not excluded anything when downloading custom zip. Do you want to create answer from your comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, a custom jquery-ui 1.11.4 zip with all components checked is not the same as the [1.11.4 stable](https://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.11.4.zip).

I downloaded both, copied the HTML from the [tabs demo page](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default) and modified the resource URLs to point to the local directory:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.structure.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.theme.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I put the exact same file in `jquery-ui-1.11.4` and `jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom` and opened it in my browser.

`jquery-ui-1.11.4`:

[image: screenshot]

`jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom`:

[image]

I was wondering why this was happening, so I went to inspect the CSS files, and I found the reason:
Most CSS selectors in the custom build are prefixed with `smoothness`, as in

```
smoothness .ui-helper-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

where the stable build uses

```
.ui-helper-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

So I went ahead and put `<smoothness></smoothness>` around the tabs `div` in my HTML, and the result looked pretty acceptable

[image]

However, I don't really know what to think of this find... I wanted to say "the custom builds aren't broken, you just have to use them differently", but that's not true - they rely on a non-existing (read: invalid) HTML element to work, which I consider "broken".

Conclusion: Unless you're fine with invalid HTML, stay away from custom jqueryUI builds, at least for now.